# User registration form works in RegistrationPage class, but not UserPage in SilverStripe 3

Tags: php, forms, routes, registration, silverstripe

I am trying to build a registration page in SilverStripe 3 and I got it working in the RegistrationPage_Controller class. But when I try to move it over to the UserPage class it suddenly doesn't want to work.

It definitely has to do with the form rendering, but given these two should be pretty much identical in implementation it has me scratching my head.

My goal is to unify registration and profile viewing and editing under the "/user" base path. So the registration page will become "/user/register". The currently working class puts it under "/register". I am new to SilverStripe and I am not finding the documentation to be all that helpful right now.

You can see the full UserPage.php file here: http://pastebin.com/JRnzh1dL

And you can see the full RegistrationPage.php file here: http://pastebin.com/mbwL6mQT

I also have a routes.yml file that contains:

```
---
Name: customroutes
Before: '*'
After:
    - '#rootroutes'
    - '#coreroutes'
    - '#modelascontrollerroutes'
    - '#adminroutes'
---
Director:
    rules:
        'register//$Action/$ID/$Name' : 'RegistrationPage_Controller'
        'user//$Action/$ID/$Name' : 'UserPage_Controller'
```

Comment: Did you flush cache after moving the form?

Comment: Yes, multiple times to be sure.

Comment: What SilverStripe version? Since SilverStripe 3.1 $allowed_actions (as the most of statics) should be private. Probably, it's the point.

Comment: I am running on SilverStripe 3.0.5. I know about the changes in 3.1, but we haven't moved to that version just yet. I would really like to get this dang thing to work.

Comment: The problem is with the rendering piece and only under the UserPage_Controller. If I put it anywhere else it works just fine.

Comment: I did not remember exactly, but on some of previous version (between 3.0 and 3.1) I had issue with not working routes.yml, so I had to add routing rules into _config.php. just ask me if you need example.

Comment: Am just wondering why you need the YAML Director rules at all? Your controllers are page controllers, so they are accessible automatically when navigating to the page via their URL segments?

Comment: Because otherwise the path would be <url>/UserPage_Controller/some_function.